# Simple HTML DOM Parser scrape data with website login

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, web-scraping

I have to scrape the data from the website https://www.mecum.com/auctions/indianapolis-2018/lots/ But this requires login to view the sale price of the car, and they use `POST` method for login.

Please let me know how to scrape the data using website login as I can login to this website on my browser to scrape the results using PHP Simple Dom Parser